# How to make single object blur

Tags: node-editor

Will i have made some render below is my image. 
[image]

I want just my dice to be blur. Is it possible only my dice to be blur and have the rest of the scene to be as it is. I have searched for the video and tried in node tree defocus but fail to get the effect.
[image]
 What is lacking in my node so that i can just blur the dice. Any suggestion or help . Thanks

**I cant see my dise**
[image]

Comment: You are mixing two different things. I guess you'd like to add *Motion Blur* rather than adjusting *Depth of Field*? Start reading here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_of_field vs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_blur

Comment: @brockmann well can u tell me what will be my nodes if i just want my dise to be blur

Comment: @brockmann just simple in my scene i want my dise to be blur just a single object (dise) to be blur

Comment: In other words: Blurring the dice only, will result in a horrible image @ateks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do compositing to selective parts of a scene by using render layers. In your case you need two render layers. The first one should contain your everything except the dice. The second one should contain your dice and have "sky" disabled. The red cube is in the normal render layer and the blue cube is in the blur render layer. Here is an example compositor setup to get the effect you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. with the reference i have render 2 image and the node setup but i cant see my dise. Plz see my image in the top in question. What im missing.

Comment: It was my mistake i did not click on composite below. Well it works. Thanks